# Where is the Video Manager in MythTV?

Tags: mythtv, mythbuntu

I can no longer find the Video Manager in new versions of MythTV. Where did it go?

Comment: do you mean the mythvideo package?  I dont follow exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MythVideo no longer needs Video Manager to edit metadata and scan for changes, this can be done from any of the MythVideo screens by hitting M then Scan for changes. See [MythVideo - Scanning for videos](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/MythVideo#Scanning_for_Videos)